# Coding HTML for email clients: Font sizes always larger in Apple Mail than Microsoft Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-table, html-email

I've been following various guides online such as the ones on Campaign Monitor to build an HTML page for viewing in email clients. To those unfamiliar, this essentially means building pages out of HTML tables and inline CSS to create the look and formatting of a normal web page. Such divergent coding behavior is due to the fact that most email clients restrict a great deal of CSS styling rules. For testing, I've been using Email on Acid to preview how my page would render across various email clients.

The problem I'm having is that text in Microsoft Outlook appears smaller than the true font size (as viewed in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari) and that the text in Apple Mail appears larger than the true font size. Since I wish to have my page look presentable across both platforms, I will need to find a remedy to this problem.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s01v.jpg) is an image showing how each platform compares. Note how the text is so large on Apple Mail that it breaks the height of the table. Not surprisingly, simply reducing the text size for Apple Mail is not an option since it will shrink the text in Outlook into oblivion.

If you are familiar with coding emails you can know that it is a messy business, and requires you to break a great deal of common sense practices in coding -- including readability. To help with perusal of the source code, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C2xl.jpg) is an image clearly marking where each table begins and ends (as viewed in Chrome). All those images named "row_xx.jpg" in the source below are just vertical gray bits that make up the border of the email. Some of these images also have some white space inside them in order to give the illusion of indenting.

Source:

```
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tr width="600">
        <td width="600" height="8">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_11.jpg' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tr width="600">
        <td width="44" height="10">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_12a.jpg' />
        </td>
        <td width="554" height="10" style="font-family:Lucida Grande;font-size: 7px;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </td>
        <td width="2" height="10">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_12c.jpg' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tr width="600">
        <td width="44" height="12">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_13a.jpg' />
        </td>
        <td width="554" height="12" style="font-family:Lucida Grande;font-size: 7px;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </td>
        <td width="2" height="12">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_13c.jpg' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tr width="600">
        <td width="44" height="12">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_14a.jpg' />
        </td>
        <td width="554" height="12" style="font-family:Lucida Grande;font-size: 7px;">
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </td>
        <td width="2" height="12">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_14c.jpg' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tr width="600">
        <td width="600" height="8">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_15.jpg' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tr width="600">
        <td width="44" height="10">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_16a.jpg' />
        </td>
        <td width="554" height="10" style="font-family:Lucida Grande;font-size: 7px;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </td>
        <td width="2" height="10">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_16c.jpg' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tr width="600">
        <td width="44" height="14">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_17a.jpg' />
        </td>
        <td width="554" height="14" style="font-family:Lucida Grande;font-size: 7px;">
            uis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
        </td>
        <td width="2" height="14">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_17c.jpg' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tr width="600">
        <td width="600" height="11">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_18.jpg' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tr width="600">
        <td width="44" height="13">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_19a.jpg' />
        </td>
        <td width="554" height="13" style="font-family:Lucida Grande;font-size: 7px;">
            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </td>
        <td width="2" height="13">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_19c.jpg' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tr width="600">
        <td width="44" height="12">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_20a.jpg' />
        </td>
        <td width="554" height="12" style="font-family:Lucida Grande;font-size: 7px;">
            =Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam. 
        </td>
        <td width="2" height="12">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_20c.jpg' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tr width="600">
        <td width="600" height="12">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_21.jpg' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tr width="600">
        <td width="44" height="12">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_22a.jpg' />
        </td>
        <td width="554" height="12" style="font-family:Lucida Grande;font-size: 7px;">
            At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti 
        </td>
        <td width="2" height="12">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_22c.jpg' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tr width="600">
        <td width="44" height="12">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_23a.jpg' />
        </td>
        <td width="554" height="12" style="font-family:Lucida Grande;font-size: 7px;">
            quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, 
        </td>
        <td width="2" height="12">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_23c.jpg' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tr width="600">
        <td width="44" height="11">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_24a.jpg' />
        </td>
        <td width="554" height="11" style="font-family:Lucida Grande;font-size: 7px;">
            similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, 
        </td>
        <td width="2" height="11">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_24c.jpg' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tr width="600">
        <td width="44" height="12">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_25a.jpg' />
        </td>
        <td width="554" height="12" style="font-family:Lucida Grande;font-size: 7px;">
            id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.
        </td>
        <td width="2" height="12">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_25c.jpg' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tr width="600">
        <td width="44" height="12">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_26a.jpg' />
        </td>
        <td width="554" height="12" style="font-family:Lucida Grande;font-size: 7px;">
             Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus,
        </td>
        <td width="2" height="12">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_26c.jpg' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tr width="600">
        <td width="600" height="24">
            <img style="display:block;border:none;" src='images/row_27.jpg' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text appearing larger in iOS devices seems to be a common issue, but I haven't heard of it happening in Apple Mail. Perhaps the fix for iOS devices for will work for you, too. Just include this in the style of text you do not want to be resized. If you don't want any text to be resized, include it in the style of the body tag.

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
```

Comment: This property does not seem to affect the text in the renders either, which is made more odd by the fact that the results of John's solution suggests that setting -webkit-text-size-adjust to either 100% or none returns the same result. Off the top of my head I feel like that indicates that this property will really only affect text in a mobile setting, but I will need to do more research on the property itself.

Comment: It looks like I spoke too soon. There is definitely something going on when I use this styling and I believe I missed it since it is still not exactly matching the text size in Chrome; regardless, it is indeed reducing the font in Apple Mail by a decent amount. I did not realize it myself until I began messing around with other ideas and disabled it. My workflow at the moment involves long waits between renders and while it is simple to see a result has not matched Chrome's style, it completely goes over my head if it had made an appreciable difference over an older render. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @user3494572 Webkit prefixes will only affect Mac clients as they are the ones that render email with the Webkit engine. Thunderbird uses Gecko which may also trigger as it is similar.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this is your `<style>` tag?

```
body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;} /* force default font sizes */
```

Obviously only the text-size stuff is relevant in this case.

If that doesn't fix it, then there is not much else you can do, unless you want to start trying to target different clients using combinations of tricks to target clients based on their varying support.

Comment: Unfortunately running this styling through preview renders has not shown any difference, although judging from the syntax I'd imagine it should have been a great solution -- adjusting text size based on webkit vs. ms covers this problem perfectly. While I suppose the text-size-adjust properties aren't mentioend on Campaign Monitor's email styling [compatibility list](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), I still would've imagined that Apple Mail would have no problem accepting it since the client would appear to already accept a great deal of different CSS rules.

Comment: This is a well known "normalization" trick for html email. See the [html email boilerplate](http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/), that most designers in the industry refer to for setting up their document. If that doesn't work, as mentioned the only way is if you start conditionally targeting clients. You can target Outlook with conditional statements, or Gmail by overwriting the inline CSS with CSS in the style tag (which Gmail doesn't support). Ultimately though, once you go the 'hack' route you are doubling your work for minimal gain, and you'll still have segmented results over major clients.

Comment: That was very informative John, I think it would be wise to use the boilerplate on future projects such as this these. I agree about the backup plan being too hacky, while still valid for the proposed circumstances. I will have to go back and doublecheck if I simply mis-tested your solution as it turns out I had with Narong's, I will let you know what I find out.